# How to keep rows order from a pandas DataFrame to a dict

Tags: python, django, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame which is already sorted by date, but I need to serialize this DataFrame to a dict python structure keeping the rows order so I can later return a JSON.

I use a dict where i have some keys and values and I need the DataFrame to be a value. I used pd.to_dict() but this doesn't keep the row ordering.

I've tried to use OrderedDict but I can't serialize this with json.dumps(). I'm using python 2.7.

```py
dic_data = {
            'data':data.to_dict(),
            'variable':variables[variable],
            'unit':units[variable],
            'limits':{
                'limite_superior':lim_sup,
                'limite_inferior':lim_inf
            }
        }

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(dic_data),content_type="application/json")
```

this is the datraframe data that im trying to convert into rows ordered dict to later serialize it in json

```
            date_time values
202   2018-09-01 10:00    0,9
203   2018-09-01 11:00    0,1
204   2018-09-01 12:00    0,0
205   2018-09-01 13:00    0,0
206   2018-09-01 14:00    0,0
207   2018-09-01 15:00    0,0
208   2018-09-01 16:00    0,0
209   2018-09-01 17:00    0,0
```

the json object that im receving from de data dataframe has the following structure:

```
{
    date_time:{
                0:"2018-09-01 20:00",
                1:"2018-09-01 21:00",
                ....
              },
    values:{
            0:20.54,
            1:30.45,
            .....
           }

}
```

and actually I need the same structure but with rows ordered.

Comment: I removed one of the less relevant tags and added the python 2.7 tag. Figured that's more important as "dictionaries are ordered in Python 3.6" so this is really a version specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `into` parameter of the `to_dict` method:

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

dic_data = {
            'data':data.to_dict(into=OrderedDict),
            'variable':variables[variable],
            'unit':units[variable],
            'limits':{
                'limite_superior':lim_sup,
                'limite_inferior':lim_inf
            }
        }
```